# "Controller as" not working with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to populate a list within a "Controller as" block, but I cannot seem to get anything to display. I've gotten a minimal example of my idea working with `$scope`:

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('testApp', []);
app.controller('listController', ["$scope", ($scope) => {
  $scope.listFiles = ["hello", "world"];
}]);
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="listController">
  <div class="list-group">
    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" ng-repeat="filename in listFiles">{{ filename }}</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jkmcx894/)

But when I introduce "Controller as", the list does not display:

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('testApp', []);

app.controller('listController', ["$scope", ($scope) => {
  var $ctrl = this;
  $ctrl.listFiles = ["hello", "world"];
}]);
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="listController as ctrl">
  <div class="list-group">
    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" ng-repeat="filename in ctrl.listFiles">{{ filename }}</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fn386yvu/)

I understand that `$scope` and `this` are different concepts, but I cannot seem to wrap my head around the specifics in this case.

Could this be a result of the scope rules for ng-repeat, or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you should not use `arrow function` while defining `controller function`, this will lead `this` to an unexpected context which not belong to controller itself. The solution is using normal `function`.

refer the below example and fixed **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wwjvfw8w/)**.

```js
var app = angular.module('testApp', []);

app.controller('listController', ["$scope", function($scope) {
  var $ctrl = this;
  this.listFiles = ["hello", "world"];
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="listController as ctrl">
  <div class="list-group">
    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" ng-repeat="filename in ctrl.listFiles">{{ filename }}</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this have anything to do with browser support for ES6 syntax?

Comment: @AlanG based on your question, it seems arrow function is working, else you will receive an error `controller is not function`. BTW, the main reason of your problem is you are using arrow function which as I answered will lead to context problems.

Answer (score 1):

You have used es6 arrow function syntax. Since the browser doesn't support es6 syntax.Either you have to use transpiler(Babel) to compile es6 code to pure javascript.

Try changing this

```
app.controller('listController', ["$scope", ($scope) => {
```

With

```
app.controller('listController', ["$scope", function($scope)  {
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/laktherock/gw6fr3dv/5/)